# My react native project does not recognize the phone theme

Tags: react-native, native-base, darkmode

I am trying to give a darkmode to the entire application but the phone theme is not recognizing me. It only returns light even if the phone is in dark mode

I have tried it with the Appearance object of react native but it only returns the light mode even if the theme is dark

I have also tried to do it with the hook const {colorMode) = useColoMode() from native-base but it doesn't work either, it only returns the light

why can this happen?